# CSV Dates in character class produce NA when converting to date or POSIX

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a data frame that has over multiple date columns which have been classed as a character. I need to change them to a date or posix class

```
library(dplyr,lubridate)
date <- c("1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM"
          ,"1/22/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM"
          ,"1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/22/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/20/2021 12:00:00 AM"
          ,"1/20/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/20/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/22/2021 12:00:00 AM"
          ,"1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/20/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/20/2021 12:00:00 AM"
          ,"1/20/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/22/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM"
          ,"1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/22/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM"
          ,"1/22/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/22/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM"
          ,"1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/22/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/22/2021 12:00:00 AM"
          ,"1/22/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM","1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM")

a <- rnorm(30)
df <- data.frame(a, date)

# A tibble: 30 × 2
        a date                 
    <dbl> <chr>                
 1 -0.823 1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM
 2 -0.312 1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM
 3 -1.12  1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM
 4 -0.508 1/22/2021 12:00:00 AM
 5  0.566 1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM
 6  0.704 1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM
 7 -0.588 1/23/2021 12:00:00 AM
 8 -1.10  1/22/2021 12:00:00 AM
 9 -1.10  1/20/2021 12:00:00 AM
10  0.579 1/20/2021 12:00:00 AM
```

Every approach I have tried has produced NAs.
I have used strptime, mdy_hms from lubridate, as.Date from base.

Any direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?strptime` offers a nice cheatsheet for the abbreviations to be used. This snippet should work in my opinion:

```r
df[["date"]] <- df[["date"]] |> strptime(format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") 

df[["date"]] |> head()
#> [1] "2021-01-23 CET" "2021-01-23 CET" "2021-01-23 CET" "2021-01-22 CET"
#> [5] "2021-01-23 CET" "2021-01-23 CET"

df[["date"]] |> class()
#> [1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

**Edit:**

Sorry, I'm not really used to `dplyr` yet so I can't really help you with `mutate()`. But you needed your date column as a `POSIX*` object and that is exactly what you got as far as I understand:

```r
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    30 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ a   : num  -0.0472 0.3096 -0.1849 -0.619 0.1552 ...
#>  $ date: POSIXlt, format: "2021-01-23" "2021-01-23" ...

tibble::as_tibble(df)
#> # A tibble: 30 × 2
#>          a date               
#>      <dbl> <dttm>             
#>  1 -0.0472 2021-01-23 00:00:00
#>  2  0.310  2021-01-23 00:00:00
#>  3 -0.185  2021-01-23 00:00:00
#>  4 -0.619  2021-01-22 00:00:00
#>  5  0.155  2021-01-23 00:00:00
#>  6  0.275  2021-01-23 00:00:00
#>  7  1.80   2021-01-23 00:00:00
#>  8  0.525  2021-01-22 00:00:00
#>  9 -0.411  2021-01-20 00:00:00
#> 10  0.460  2021-01-20 00:00:00
#> # … with 20 more rows
#> # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: This is the closest I have gotten with your method, issue is now it creates the column as a list class of both the POSIXlt and POSIX version.

Is there a method you would use to apply this but using a mutate?

Comment: I got this approach to work, a bit of a modification since I was using dplyr.

I first stripped off the time portion using str_remove, then wrapped everything in a mutate function.


`df_new <- df %>% mutate(date = str_remove(date, " 12:00:00 AM"),`
   `date = as.Date(strptime(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")))`

Comment: Ah, I see what you did there. You can omit the `str_remove` part if you go for a more detailed format specification, e.g. `df |> mutate(date = as.Date(strptime(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")))`.

Comment: Ah, yeah make sense. The time was just an artifact of garbage input in a database so it was going to get striped out one way or another. Thanks again, you solved a headache.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `anydate()` from the `library(anytime)` package.

`newdate <- anydate(date)`

`tibble(a,newdate)`

```
A tibble: 30 x 2
     a date      
 <dbl> <date>    
 1  0.444  2021-01-23
 2 -0.0288 2021-01-23
 3 -0.607  2021-01-23
 4  0.371  2021-01-22
 5  0.502  2021-01-23
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me;
Error in anytime_cpp(x = x, tz = tz, asUTC = asUTC, asDate = TRUE, useR = useR,  : 
  Unsupported Type
I am not familiar with this package.

Comment: and using anytime() instead of anydate() leads to the same error?       
anytime(date,useR = TRUE)

Comment: same error, no change. Seems like it can't parse the format its in.